# How to solve recursion T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/3)+n?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, recurrence-relation, recursion

How to solve recursion $T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/3)+n$? I do not really know how to approach this kind of recurrence.

Comment: Use the Akra-Bazzi theorem.

Comment: I know the theorem but i do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward application of the Akra-Bazzi theorem.

You can also show that $T(n) = \Theta(n)$ by induction. First, clearly $T(n) \geq n$. In the other direction, if we have shown that $T(m) \leq 6m$ for $m < n$, then
$$
T(n) \leq 6(n/2 + n/3) + n = 6n.
$$
Therefore as long as the base case holds, and if we ignore the fact that $n/2,n/3$ are not necessarily integers, we can prove inductively that $T(n) \leq 6n$.

Comment: Thank you! If i do not bother you, can you please detail steps for proving it by induction? I applied the Akra-Bazzi after some research, but i need to prove it by induction too. Have a nice day!

Comment: I'm not going to do the exercise for you.